# jOOQ - lock in choice between `TABLES` and `ENTITIES`

Tags: jooq, jooq-codegen

jOOQ seems to switch between using `TABLES` and plural `STMTS` to `ENTITIES` and singular `STMT` in jOOQ-internal classes for no clear discernable reason.

Those needless changes kind of pollute our git commits and I am hoping to stabilise them.

What is causing those switches, and can we lock in jOOQ into either?

[image]

One thing that's being bounced around as an idea is developer platform? (MacOS vs Linux, in this case). Database runs in a docker container, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Known issues

The problem here is that the overload ordering algorithm may not be stable for PostgreSQL overloaded functions. Relevant issues include:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14039

Historic issues:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4034
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8589
- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9754

#### Workarounds

Workarounds include:

- To generate your own stable class and method names for overloaded functions, using a custom [`GeneratorStrategy`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-generatorstrategy/).
- Avoid overloading, that's going to work even better. With named and defaulted parameters, overloads may not really be necessary.